# Making entire li be a link with js

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, css

I'm populating slides on a slider with php using wp cms. At the bottom of eash slide there is a link. I need to target each slide (li) and when clicking anywhere inside the li it should link to the url on the link whithing the specific slide.

Here is the markup I need to write the js for:

```
<div class="carousel">
    <?php 
        $i = 1; 
        while( has_sub_fields( 'bottom_content' ) ): 
    ?>
    <li>
        <div class="bottom-thumb">
            <?php if( get_sub_field( 'thumb' ) ) :?><img src="<?php the_sub_field('thumb'); ?>" alt=""><?php endif; ?>
        </div>
        <h6 class="content-type"><?php the_sub_field( 'content_type' ); ?></h6>
        <p class="content-desc">
            <a href="<?php the_sub_field( 'url' ); ?>">
                <?php the_sub_field( 'title' ); ?>
            </a>
        </p>
        <div class="white-arrow"></div>
    </li>
    <?php 

        $i++;
        endwhile; 
    ?>
</ul>
```

I belive my js should be something similar to:

```
$(".carousel li").click(function(){
    $(this).find("a").attr("href");
    ...
});
```

Comment: Please post the code you have tried to make this work. Without seeing what you have tried we don't know much about how to help you.

Comment: can you use `window.location.href= $(this).find("a").attr("href");`

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can try the following:

```
<li onclick="window.location.href='<?php the_sub_field( 'url' ); ?>'">
```

Hope it helps :)

Comment: You should avoid inline event handlers for the same reason we try to avoid inline css. There's no reason to have that onclick inline instead of as he has it above.

Answer (score 1):

If the link, is clicked, fine -- user will navigate to url, and if not, you can navigate to url as follows:

```
$(".carousel li").click(function(e){
    $(e.target).is('a') || $(this).find('a')[0].click();
});
```

```js
$(".carousel li").click(function(e){
        $(e.target).is('a') || $(this).find('a')[0].click();
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="carousel">
  <ul>
    <li>
        <div class="bottom-thumb">No Link
            <?php if( get_sub_field( 'thumb' ) ) :?><img src="<?php the_sub_field('thumb'); ?>" alt=""><?php endif; ?>
        </div>
        <h6 class="content-type"><?php the_sub_field( 'content_type' ); ?></h6>
        <p class="content-desc">
            <a href="/">
                Link
            </a>
        </p>
        <div class="white-arrow"></div>
    </li>
</ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This won't work: `.click()` triggers only events attached by jQuery, not native ones.

Comment: @MartinErnst, you're absolutely right. Thanks! Triggering the native event should fix that.